# Dire need to make Bootcamp work with Thunderbolt Display

Tags: bootcamp, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display

According to [this Apple KB article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204154), it's not possible to re-connect a Thunderbolt Display to Windows Bootcamp without restarting the computer.

> A directly-connected Thunderbolt device that is removed by
>   disconnecting the Thunderbolt cable will not be recognized until you
>   restart the computer.

But if the reboot sequence is able to send a signal to the display to power up, surely it must be possible to write some code that will run in Windows and do the same thing?

Are there any tools out that can do this, or anyone with competence on the area that would be interested in writing a tool to do so?

Comment: I've edited your question slightly to keep it within the on-topic guidelines defined in the [FAQ].

Answer (score 2):

As the source of that info is Apple themselves, you'd imagine that they're probably best placed to offer advice on the subject.

This suggests that the 'fault' is not just Apple's, but requires Windows to be complicit. It would appear Windows 8 is capable, but requires the latest Apple hardware too.

Quote

> **Are Thunderbolt devices “hot pluggable” using Windows with Boot Camp?**
>   The iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, Late 2014) and the Mac mini (Late 2014) support “hot pluggable” Thunderbolt devices using Windows 8 or 8.1 (both as 64-bit only).
>   For all other Mac computers, Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 scans and activates Thunderbolt devices connected to Thunderbolt ports only during the Windows startup process. If your device was not plugged in at start up, Windows will not detect it without a restart.

Comment: Does this mean that a future version of Windows (ie. Windows 10) may or will support this? It sounds that way. Has anyone tested this?

Comment: It may - yet likely it would not be retroactive - i.e. not work with anything older than the current generation Macs.